# how to create a dynamic link buttons by user given value in textbox on an asp page load?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

1.my idea is to generate the link buttons according to supplied integer value by the user in text box 
2. that link buttons which are generated dynamically should be able that user to browse to the URL specified.

I could able to write the code for dynamic link button generations but could not able to overcome the POST BACK EVENTS which makes the link buttons  disappear.

hope u understand my requirement

please help.

Comment: that 2 in first line is meant for 2nd point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is where `return` is used. You are creating dynamic buttons, I guess using jQuery or JavaScript. Right?

Then you can use this code at the end of the function call. Like this:

```
function createButton () {
  /* either this at the top or anywhere, top is recommended */
  event.preventDefault();
  /* or, all the code here, and then this */
  return false;
}
```

Using this, you will prevent the POST BACK, and the code won't be submitted, which is the default property of a submit button. To submit the form to the server. This code would prevent the code to be sent to the server. And you will be able to see your function being executed.

Comment: I am sure it would work for C# too, otherwise you can use variables to create the button on a POST BACK.

Comment: iam new to this world of .NET so pls guide me in all the means u can by providing good links and easy way to understand for a beginner

Comment: in page load method i am trying to use the IF condition (is post back=TRUE) and if its true can i call the button click event again for the dynamic link buttons to execute

Answer (score 0):

```
i found an answer to my question which i posted some days back.......hope this is useful  to anybody who is new to ...

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        LinkButton[] linkBtn;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Session["objLinkBtn"] != null)
            {
                linkBtn = (LinkButton[])Session["objLinkBtn"];
                for (int i = 0; i < linkBtn.Length; i++)
                {
                    linkBtn[i] = new LinkButton();
                    linkBtn[i].Text = "Link" + (i + 1);
                    linkBtn[i].Click += new EventHandler(WebForm1_Click);
                    pnlLinks.Controls.Add(linkBtn[i]);
                }
                Session["objLinkBtn"] = linkBtn;
            }
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;


            if (int.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out x))
            {
                linkBtn = new LinkButton[x];
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                {
                    linkBtn[i] = new LinkButton();
                    linkBtn[i].Text = "Link" + (i + 1);
                    linkBtn[i].Click += new EventHandler(WebForm1_Click);
                    pnlLinks.Controls.Add(linkBtn[i]);
                }
                Session["objLinkBtn"] = linkBtn;
            }
        }

        void WebForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
            int ctrlNo = int.Parse(btn.Text.Replace("Link", ""));

            switch (ctrlNo)
            {
                case 1: Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com"); break;
                case 2: Response.Redirect("http://www.gmail.com"); break;
                case 3: Response.Redirect("http://www.youtube.com"); break;
                default: Response.Redirect("http://www.facebook.com"); break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```